# how to check if a method is called or not in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems

as i try to check internally my method was calling or not in rspec but it got the following errors

```
context "#Meeting_schedule" do
    let(:meeting_schedule) { FactoryGirl.create(:meeting_schedule,:time=>"morning",:schedule_name=>"planned_meet", :schedule_info=>[{ "from"=>"00:00", "to"=>"00:01"}]) }

    it "if the same schedule was created again dont save it again" do 
      schedule.save
      params = {:time=>"morning",:schedule_name=>"planned_meet", :schedule_info=>[{ "from"=>"00:00", "to"=>"00:01"}]}
      meeting_schedule.create_or_update_meeting_schedule(params)
      expect(meeting_schedule).to receive(:updating_the_user)
    end
  end
```

i got the following error

```
Failure/Error: expect(meeting_schedule.create_or_update_meeting_schedule(params)).to receive(:updating_the_user)
       (#<Meeting_schedule:0x0055dbaf0da710>).updating_the_user(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/models/meeting_schedule_spec.rb:122:in `block (4 levels)
```

so what was wrong in my code?

my method

```
def create_or_update_meeting_schedule(params)
   self.attributes = params
   if self.changed and self.save
     updating_the_user
   end
   self
end
```

can anyone help me out

Comment: You first run the code, then set up the expectation. Switch that order.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i had modified accoringly, but again the same error

Comment: Nope, the order is still the same.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev as this line will execute first meeting_schedule.create_or_update_meeting_schedule(params) and then after that only i had set the expectation, so whether is this the thing u mentioned

Comment: in line no 7 meeting_schedule.create_or_update_meeting_schedule(params) so the funciton gets executed and in line no 8 ,i set up the expectation

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I'm talking about. First set up the expectation, then run the code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks , that works, but could you plese explain why we need to set the expectations at first and then the code next?

Comment: You can also use `.to have_received` and keep the order.

Comment: @HubertJakubiak that requires you to [set the object up as a spy](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies) beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Mocks must always be setup before the method under test is called as there is no reliable way to test if a normal method was called in Ruby. There are two ways of doing this in RSpec.

The first is using [`expect(...).to receive(...)`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/basics/expecting-messages) which must be done before the method is called - this [detaches the method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/UnboundMethod.html) and replaces it with a mock that wraps the original method.

The test will fail if the method is not called in the example.

The second is [by using *spies*](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies). You can either replace an entire object with a spy:

```
RSpec.describe "have_received" do
  it "passes when the message has been received" do
    invitation = spy('invitation')
    invitation.deliver
    expect(invitation).to have_received(:deliver)
  end
end
```

This "spy object" will keep track of any method you call on it.

You can also spy on a single method:

```
class Invitation
  def self.deliver; end
end

RSpec.describe "have_received" do
  it "passes when the expectation is met" do
    allow(Invitation).to receive(:deliver)
    Invitation.deliver
    expect(Invitation).to have_received(:deliver)
  end
end
```

Spies are very useful in the case when you want to mock the method in the test setup - for example in the `before` block.

```
class Invitation
  def self.deliver; end
end

RSpec.describe "have_received" do
  before do
    allow(Invitation).to receive(:deliver)
  end

  it "passes when the expectation is met" do
    Invitation.deliver
    expect(Invitation).to have_received(:deliver)
  end
end
```